# Running an logging a python script through batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a python script called "AI_V.0.0.0.1_G.1.py".

Right when the script starts I defined current time with the time so I did this:

```
set currenttime=%time%
```

If I just run:

```
AI_V.0.0.0.1_G.1.py
```

Then it ends up perfect. The problem is that I need to log it. When I run this:

```
AI_V.0.0.0.1_G.1.py>>%currenttime%.log
```

Then it say's

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any help?

Comment: `echo %currenttime%` does nothing for me, but `echo %time%` does. Trouble is, it contains `:` which isn't a valid character in a path apart from with drive letters.

Comment: @AjVJsy Sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it uses `%time%` and replaces `:` with `-`
e.g. `18-04-54.22.log`

```
AI_V.0.0.0.1_G.1.py>>%time::=-%.log
```

Comment: Thanks, I found out though that I can't log it at all because it doesn't show to output of the script when it's running. That does make it work though.